# findstr test if contains characters other thank given batch

Tags: batch, findstr

I have a batch script where user input is needed. However, I only want to allow `a-z, 0-9, @#$].~+-=_/\:;`. Is there a way to use findstr to make sure there are no characters other than those? I've checked the documentation and cant figure out a way to get this done.

What I have:

```
@echo off
echo Enter Username:
set /p usr=">"
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you also posted your batch file. Can you edit your question and add the batch file?

Comment: Yep. Although LotPings answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use findstr default regex mode and use a [characterclass] escaping chars with a special meaning with a backslash.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\07\SU_1381655.cmd
@Echo off
:loop
set /p "input=Enter data(a-z, 0-9, @#$].~+-=_/\:;.:)"

Echo:%input%|findstr /I "^[a-z0-9@#$\]\.~+\-=_\/\\:;]*$" >NUL 2>&1 && (
   echo checked input ok
) || (
   echo invalid input
)
goto :loop
```

Check yourself if I got all chars right.
If only lower case letters were intended remove the /i switch.

---

As possible `poisenous` chars `<|>&` are echoed unquoted they may break the batch.